# Creating threads for GUI and Buttons

Tags: python, multithreading, time, raspberry-pi, sleep

I'm currently trying to build a security system on my raspberry pi. I have 9 buttons to enter a code. Once the code is entered u can press "arm" to arm the system. Then a function checks a PIR sensor for movement. When movement is detected an alarm should go off, for which I need time.sleep. 
So my actual problem is, with time.sleep I block the programm for the time its sleeping, thus i cant disarm the system during alarm mode.

My idea so far was just to put everything into threads. But without success so far. Are there any better solutions to time.sleep?

Comment: Is checking the PIR sensor something that blocks, or does it take a long time? Or is it possible to poll it every couple of seconds?

Comment: The PIR is not blocking. When the alarm is triggered a buzzer makes a sound every two seconds. Therefore i need to set the buzzer HIGH then sleep 2 secs and then set the buzzer LOW again, and so on.

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Use [interrupts](https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/rpio_py.html#gpio-interrupts). There's a keyword argument to call the callback function within a separate thread

Comment: You can use threads as long as they don't interact directly with the GUI (assuming it's tkinter-based). However, instead of `time.sleep(delay)` you can use `w.after(delay)` where `w` is any tkinter widget (and `delay` is in milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use threads. With tkinter you can easily schedule a function to run every couple of seconds in the main thread to check the sensor or do any other work that you want.

Here's a short contrived example, which will work just fine assuming that the sensor check doesn't take more than a couple hundred milliseconds. It's not exactly how I would do it, but it illustrates how you can  have some function run periodically without having to put the UI to sleep.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self._job_id = None
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, width=6, text="Arm", command=self.arm)
        self.button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def arm(self):
        self.button.configure(text="Disarm", command=self.disarm)
        self.poll()

    def disarm(self):
        self.button.configure(text="Arm", command=self.arm)

        if self._job_id:
            self.root.after_cancel(self._job_id)

    def poll(self):
        # ... check the sensor here ...
        movement = True

        if movement:
            print("beep!")

        self._job_id = self.root.after(2000, self.poll)
app = App()
app.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is simply looking for a better method to use then time.sleep, you could consider using time.time rather than time.sleep and then use checks to see what actions should occur. This would avoid using time.sleep which blocks all events (including your GUI). As a quickly written example to demonstrate this idea:

```
from time import time

millis = lambda: int(time() * 1000)

def updateAlarm(lastTime, beepRate, currentState):
    now = millis()
    if now > (lastTime + beepRate):
        return (not(currentState), now)
    return (currentState, now)


last = millis() #set the first time for the alarm
rate = 2000 # change state every two seconds
state = False # the alarm is currently off

while True: # just for demonstration purposes, while True: won't work inside of a tkinter GUI
    change = updateAlarm(last, rate, state)
    if change[0] != state: # if the state has changed, update it and print
        state = change[0]
        last = change[1]
        print(state)
```

Depending on your implementation, this may make more sense, especially if you are not using tkinter. Personally, I think Bryan's solution is much more elegant, especially since it doesn't require constantly checking the alarm to see if it needs to update.